# richfaces + index.xhtml having errors

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I have been unable to get my index.xhtml file to load properly, and I have checked all the tutorials for this. Can somebody please point me in the right direction? I was only going through the tutorials on the richfaces site.

Below is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>Greeter</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Faces Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Loader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mounza.common.Loader</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about the `<welcome-file>`, right? It **must** point to a *physically existing* file, because that's internally been used by the servletcontainer to show the default resource whenever a folder is been requested. The servletcontainer will first check if the file exists before performing a forward on this. If the file doesn't exist, you'll just get a 404.

Combining this with JSF which get executed on a virtual URL only requires a special trick. You basically need to fool the servletcontainer with a physically existing but *empty* `index.jsf` file there in the folder next to your real `index.xhtml` file. This way the servletcontainer won't show a 404, but perform a forward to the file which will automatically trigger the `FacesServlet`.

But if you happen to already use JSF 2.x (which doesn't seem to be the case, but anyway, just for sake of completeness), then you can also just change the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` from `*.jsf` (and `/faces/*`) to `*.xhtml`. This way you do not need to fiddle with virtual URLs anymore. This is not possible in JSF 1.x, because the `FacesServlet` would keep calling itself in an infinite loop.