# javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX not working

Tags: jsf, servlets, navigation, facelets, web.xml

Ive been reading some posts about javax.faces.default_suffix but without success when trying to implement it.

Using : jsf 2.0, jboss 7.1, Mojarra 2.1.5

- I need to show in URL the following : localhost:8080/myproject/index.jsf
- when navigating also need show the xxx.jsf

**web.xml**

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/comum/inicio/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>  **have tried *.jsf but with no success**
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.jsf</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Would you help me on this issue please ? thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're mixing the meaning of the default suffix and the URL pattern.

The `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` represents the default suffix of the **physical** file you've in your webapplication which represents a JSF file. This defaults in JSF 2.0 to `.xhtml`. If you change it to `.jsf`, then you should rename all physical files from `some.xhtml` to `some.jsf`. This makes generally no utter sense. You should not do that, just get rid of that context param altogether.

The `<url-pattern>` represents the default URL pattern which the enduser has to use in request URL in order to invoke the `FacesServlet` (which in turn uses the default suffix configuration to locate the physical file based on the URL). You said that you want to use `*.jsf` in URLs, however you have set it to `*.xhtml`. This is not right and changing the default suffix is not the right solution.

You should just set the URL pattern alone, not the default suffix.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This way `http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.jsf` will work.

Then there's a third problem: you're completely misunderstanding the purpose of the welcome file. It should not represent the path to the homepage. It should represent the filename of the physical file which you'd like to serve up as default file when a folder like `/`, `/foo/`, `/foo/bar/`, etc is requested. Just set it to `index.jsf`.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

However, you should keep in mind that the container will verify the existence of the physical file before continuing the request, so that it can properly show a 404 error if absent. As `*.jsf` is actually a virtual URL, that step will fail. You can solve that by fooling the container by placing a physically existing but **empty** `index.jsf` file next to the `index.xhtml` file in the desired folder.

This way `http://localhost:8080/myproject/` will work, provided that you have a real `index.xhtml` file and empty `index.jsf` file in the root folder.

Much easier is to just get rid of virtual URLs and stick to `*.xhtml` all the time.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/)
- [JSF welcome file is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885874/jsf-welcome-file-not-recognized/7889247#7889247)
- [richfaces + index.xhtml having errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642356/richfaces-index-xhtml-having-errors/9644205#9644205)

Comment: **[RESOLVED]** Just perfect @BalusC .You are right about simplicity. Why to complicate it? I prefer to stick *.xhtml only. thanks again

Comment: How is `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` useful? It does not do anything right?

Comment: I have a problem. Everything is working but if I go to /index.xhtml file I get the xhtml source code (bypassing JSF processing, so user can see the JSF2 tags, etc). Id like .xhtml to be processed as if .jsf suffix was used. How can I achieve that? (I've tried including a servlet-mapping for *.xhtml, but it does not work)

Comment: @icordoba: Since JSF 2 you can use *.xhtml as the URL pattern. This makes it impossible to access the source file.